# Laravel remove /index.php/ in URLs and forcing HTTPS

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

All that trick worked correctly and I have been hacked by someone, and I have no more HTTPS redirect forcing and /index.php/ in URLs here...

Here is my public/.htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

When I add :

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.+) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

All my URLs have a `404 error`!

Can you help, please?

New `.htaccess`:
https working
still have /index.php/ in URL (do not remove it) :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule (.*) /index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Add below two lines at the end of your .htaccess and before closing IfModule tag
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

To remove index.php from the url try:

enable mod_rewrite in php.ini

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.+) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @dev but still index.php in URLs

Comment: @LienLien I have updated code to remove index.php from the url path. Try that.

Comment: it does not work. I have no 404 or 500 error but I still have /index.php/ in URLs. I edit my original post so you can view my htaccess

Comment: Have you enabled mod_rewrite ?

Comment: and restarted server after enabling mode-rewrite?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^index.php/(.+) /$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: With that I have 404 erors everywhere